Flutter Youtube Error (Video not loading)
So I tried to make a flutter page that plays youtube shorts but the problem is the youtube video is not loading/playing. It's just the circular progress indicator. I have tried looking online but can't seem to figure it out. ChatGPT also is of no help. Would really appreciate if you can help me solve this issue.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:youtube_player_flutter/youtube_player_flutter.dart';

class MiddlePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MiddlePageState createState() => _MiddlePageState();
}

class _MiddlePageState extends State<MiddlePage> {
  late YoutubePlayerController _controller;
  bool _isPlayerReady = false;
  String? _videoId;
  PlayerState _playerState = PlayerState.unknown;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _videoId = YoutubePlayer.convertUrlToId('https://youtube.com/shorts/SXHMnicI6Pg?si=wBne89CuzcNB4Jyt');
    if (_videoId == null) {
      print('Error: Could not extract video ID.');
    } else {
      _controller = YoutubePlayerController(
        initialVideoId: _videoId!,
        flags: YoutubePlayerFlags(
          autoPlay: true,
          mute: false,
        ),
      )..addListener(_videoPlayerListener);
    }
  }

  void _videoPlayerListener() {
    if (_controller.value.isReady && !_isPlayerReady) {
      setState(() {
        _isPlayerReady = true;
        _playerState = _controller.value.playerState;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Center(
              child: _isPlayerReady
                  ? YoutubePlayer(
                      controller: _controller,
                      showVideoProgressIndicator: true,
                      progressIndicatorColor: Colors.red,
                      onReady: () {
                        print('Player is ready.');
                      },
                      onEnded: (metadata) {
                        print('Video Ended');
                      },
                    )
                  : _videoId == null
                      ? Text(
                          'Could not load video',
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                        )
                      : CircularProgressIndicator(),
            ),
            if (!_isPlayerReady && _videoId != null)
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        'Video Title',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 18,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 4),
                      Text(
                        'Username',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 16,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

I am trying to make a page similar to youtube shorts page but the video is not loading.

In your code this change then check:
bool _isPlayerReady = true;

